# Converting SQL query to ElasticSearch Query

Tags: caching, elasticsearch

I want to convert the following sql query to Elasticsearch one. can any one help in this.

```
select csgg, sum(amount) from table1
where type in ('a','b','c') and year=2016 and fc="33" group by csgg having sum(amount)=0
```

I tried following way:`enter code here`

```
{
  "size": 500,
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                 {"term" : {"fc" : "33"}},
                 {"term" : {"year" : 2016}} 
              ],
              "should" : [
                {"terms" : {"type" : ["a","b","c"] }}   
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_csgg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "csgg"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_amount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but not sure if I am doing right as its not validating the results.
seems query to be added inside aggregation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you use Elasticsearch 2.x, there is a possibility to have the *having*-semantics in Elasticsearch.
I'm not aware of a possibility prior 2.0.

You can use the new Pipeline Aggregation [Bucket Selector Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html), which only selects the buckets, which meet a certain criteria:

```
POST test/test/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query" : {
      "constant_score" : { 
         "filter" : {
            "bool" : {
              "must" : [
                 {"term" : {"fc" : "33"}},
                 {"term" : {"year" : 2016}},
                 {"terms" : {"type" : ["a","b","c"] }}
              ]
           }
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
    "group_by_csgg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "csgg",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_amount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        },
        "no_amount_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {"sumAmount": "sum_amount"},
            "script": "sumAmount == 0"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However there are two caveats. Depending on your configuration, it might be necessary to [enable scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) like that:

```
script.aggs: true
script.groovy: true
```

Moreover, as it works on the parent buckets it is not guaranteed that you get all buckets with amount = 0. If the terms aggregation selects only terms with sum amount != 0, you will have no result.

Comment: what action to be taken for following: 
script.aggs: true
script.groovy: true It also says like following:  Parse Failure [Could not find aggregator type [bucket_selector] in [no_amount_filter]]]; }]

Comment: Do you use Elasticsearch version >= 2.0.0 ? For me it sounds like you are using a 1.x version.