# group by using aggregation in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to query on elastic search by following the sql query and I want to implement same logic using Java API.

```
SELECT pid FROM test GROUP BY pid HAVING COUNT(id) > 1;
```

As i am new to ES i don't understand aggregations that well. please suggest how to implement the above using Java API.

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823045/converting-sql-query-to-elasticsearch-query/36825826#36825826 Perhaps, this helps to build a solution with the java api.

Comment: Thanks Michael...that helped a lot..